# How to call native C from C# when C is hosting the CLR

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I have a C program that is able to host the CLR and call C# methods just fine.  (I'm using HostFxr.)  I now want to call a native C function from C#.  There are some examples on the net, but I can't find any for the case that the C program is hosting the CLR.  I am doing this on Linux.

Any pointers would sure be appreciated.

Thanks!

Blake McBride

Comment: Try decorating a C function with `extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default")))`, then use `[DllImport]` with the name of your application binary containing that function.

Comment: Thanks.  First, I am using C, not C++.  Second, my app is hosting the CLR.

Comment: 1 – in this case remove the `"C"`. I don’t think #2 matters. When you ask `dlopen` to load a binary that’s already loaded into the current process, you’ll get the old instance without doing any disk IO, i.e. very fast. I think it should work for the main binary as well.

Comment: Very likely there’s another, more idiomatic way. However, I’m pretty sure it’s more complicated to implement. `[DllImport]` is fast on all platforms, and widely used by .NET runtime library to call various OS components.

Comment: I kind of doubt the [DllImport] could work correctly because I need the call to occur in-context.  That means whatever global variables are in the C environment when it called C# should be available to the called C function.

Comment: C functions don't have contexts. Global variables are allocated by compiler and linker, they have a single copy for the complete process, regardless how many times you called `dlopen` / `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: Mono had DllImport("__Internal",...     The "__Internal" caused it to use the function inside the hosting environment.  It doesn't work with the Microsoft CLR and the Mono CLR link doesn't work anymore either.

Comment: Try `"yourprogram"` instead, where `yourprogram` is your native binary hosting the .NET.

Comment: @BlakeMcBride this is a very good question, have you found any way how to solve your task?